# Enter Two Date and Record Show Per Day Count Wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

plz Solve My Table test

```
Id int
Emp_ID int
ontime Datetime
```

select * from test

```
Id  Emp_ID  ontime 
1   1   2013-02-11 2:14:25.387  
2   2   2013-02-11 14:14:25.387
1   1   2013-02-11 20:14:25.387
3   3   2013-02-13 10:14:25.387
4   2   2013-02-13 10:14:25.387
5   1   2013-02-13 10:14:25.387
6   1   2013-02-14 11:14:25.387
```

My requirement This

user Enter Two Date and Record Show Per Day Count Wise

just record

Date 1=11/2/2013
Date 2=13/2/2013

```
Emp_ID  11/2/2013   12/2/2013   13/2/2013
1       2       0       1
2       1       0       1
3       0       0       1
```

thx

---

tHx

but this one tbl_emp

Emp_ID  int
Emp_name varchar

```
| EMP_ID | 2013-02-11 | 2013-02-12 | 2013-02-13 |
-------------------------------------------------
|      1 |          2 |          0 |          1 |
|      2 |          1 |          0 |          1 |
|      3 |          0 |          0 |          1 |
|      4 |          0 |          0 |          0 |
```

Emp_ID  4 not insert in test table

Comment: Look at `PIVOT` with conjunction dynamic sql.

Answer (score 3):

This type of data transformation is known as a `PIVOT`. Starting in SQL Server 2005 there is a function that will perform this for you.

If you know the values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the query similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select id,
    [Emp_ID], 
    cast([ontime] as date) ontime
  from test
) src
pivot
(
  count(id)
  for ontime in ([2013-02-11], [2013-02-12], [2013-02-13])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba823/7).

If you have an unknown number of columns to transform, then you will want to use dynamic SQL. This can be further filtered by using a `WHERE` clause to find only certain dates:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cast([ontime] as date)) 
                    from test
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT emp_id,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Emp_ID pivId,
                  [Emp_ID], 
                  cast([ontime] as date) ontime
                from test
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(pivId)
                for ontime in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba823/15).

If you want to guarantee that you will return the dates that you want, then you can generate a list of dates first.  So you entire dynamic SQL script will be:

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '2013-02-11'
set @enddate = '2013-02-13'

;with cte (startdate) as
(
  select @startdate
  union all
  select DATEADD(dd, 1, startdate)
  from cte
  where DATEADD(dd, 1, startdate) <= @enddate
)
select *
into #tempDates
from cte;    

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(startdate as date)) 
                    from #tempDates
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT emp_id,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Emp_ID pivId,
                  [Emp_ID], 
                  cast([ontime] as date) ontime
                from test
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(pivId)
                for ontime in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84ad0/4).  This returns the result:

```
| EMP_ID | 2013-02-11 | 2013-02-12 | 2013-02-13 |
-------------------------------------------------
|      1 |          2 |          0 |          1 |
|      2 |          1 |          0 |          1 |
|      3 |          0 |          0 |          1 |
```

Edit #1, if you want to include all employees, then you will want to use a JOIN on another table and your code would be similar to this:

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '2013-02-11'
set @enddate = '2013-02-13'

;with cte (startdate) as
(
  select @startdate
  union all
  select DATEADD(dd, 1, startdate)
  from cte
  where DATEADD(dd, 1, startdate) <= @enddate
)
select *
into #tempDates
from cte;    

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(startdate as date)) 
                    from #tempDates
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT emp_id, Emp_name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select e.Emp_ID pivId,
                  e.[Emp_ID], 
                  e.Emp_name,
                  cast([ontime] as date) ontime
                from Emp_Table e
                left join test t
                  on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(pivId)
                for ontime in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e561/5)

Comment: tHx

but this one tbl_emp

Emp_ID int Emp_name varchar
<pre>
| EMP_ID | 2013-02-11 | 2013-02-12 | 2013-02-13 |
-------------------------------------------------
|      1 |          2 |          0 |          1 |
|      2 |          1 |          0 |          1 |
|      3 |          0 |          0 |          1 |
|      4 |          0 |          0 |          0 |
Emp_ID 4 not insert in test table

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal you did not include Emp_ID 4 in the test data

Comment: yes not include Emp_ID 4 in the test data  but this one tbl_emp
(Emp_ID int, Emp_name varchar)

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal can your edit your original post with the correct data? Or edit this sql fiddle with correct data -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84ad0/4

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal see my edit, you will want to use a `JOIN` between the `EMP_table` and the other table to get a list of all employees. Here is a working demo --http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e561/5